# How do I remove an extra space and commas in a field SQL?

Tags: sql-server, excel, replace

I'm trying to copy some data from SQL Server 2014 to Excel but because of an extra space in some of the records the data is being split between two columns when copied over.

I have used this code to stop columns from splitting onto different rows:

```
REPLACE(REPLACE(*field* ,CHAR(10),' '),CHAR(13),' ')
```

However I'm unsure how to also remove the extra space from the same field.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The TRIM() function will remove leading spaces, trailing spaces and replace multiple spaces with a single space.

Comment: Will this be done using SQL Server or Excel?

Comment: Thanks for your help! I would rather this be done using SQL server

Answer (score 0):

- TRIM function will fix the issue
- Say you have a string '  ABC     '(2 spaces followed by 'ABC' followed by 5 spaces) and you need the output to be only 'ABC'
- TRIM(<string_column>, ' \t') would fix this
- Query for the example string : SELECT TRIM('  ABC     ', ' \t') FROM DUAL; Output: 'ABC'

Comment: Thank you! Can this be used in line with the code I have detailed in the question? This prevents the data from splitting onto different rows

Comment: Yes it can be used

Comment: Note that TRIM does not exist  in version 2016 and older versions. Use LTRIM and RTRIM instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to remove Char(10) + Char(13), you can still use replace(), just replace with the empty string:

```
DECLARE @myfield varchar(50) = CONCAT('This is a test', CHAR(10), CHAR(13));
SELECT mynewfield = REPLACE(@myfield, char(10) + char(13), '');
```

Alternatively replace with a space if that was your intention (' ').